# How to create a secret in Google Cloud Secret Manager by Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-secret-manager, secret-manager

This is official page: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/secret_manager_secret

I created these files:

variables.tf

```
variable gcp_project {
  type = string
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "my_password" {
  provider = google-beta

  secret_id = "my-password"

  replication {
    automatic = true
  }
}

data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "my_password_v1" {
  provider = google-beta
  project  = var.gcp_project
  secret   = google_secret_manager_secret.my_password.secret_id
  version  = 1
}
```

outputs.tf

```
output my_password_version {
  value = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.my_password_v1.version
}
```

When apply it, got error:

```
Error: Error retrieving available secret manager secret versions: googleapi: Error 404: Secret Version [projects/2381824501/secrets/my-password/versions/1] not found.
```

So I created the secret by gcloud cli:

```
echo -n "my_secret_password" | gcloud secrets create "my-password" \
    --data-file - \
    --replication-policy "automatic"
```

Then apply terraform again, it said `Error: project: required field is not set`.

If use terraform to create a secret with a real value, how to do?

Comment: Did you set correctly `var.gcp_project`? It is not shown what it is in your question.

Comment: Yes, this variable doesn't matter.

Comment: Did you set up the project in the global provider block?

Comment: @RyanSiu Yes, I did.

Comment: You’re using a data source. You need to use the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following article that I consider to be useful on [Managing Secret Manager with Terraform](https://www.sethvargo.com/managing-google-secret-manager-secrets-with-terraform/).

You have to:

1. Create the Setup
2. Create a file named `versions.tf` that define the version constraints.
3. Create a file named `main.tf` and configure the Google provider stanza:

This is the code for creating a Secret Manager secret named "my-secret" with an automatic replication policy:

```
resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "my-secret" {
  provider = google-beta

  secret_id = "my-secret"

  replication {
    automatic = true
  }

  depends_on = [google_project_service.secretmanager]
}
```

Comment: Use this method how to export its value from output for other modules?

Comment: Have a careful read to the security note of the Seth Vargo article.

Answer (score 0):

Following @marian.vladoi's answer, if you're having issues with cloud resource manager api, enable it like so:

```
resource "google_project_service" "cloudresourcemanager" {
  service = "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable the cloud resource manager api using this gcloud command in terminal:

```
gcloud services enable secretmanager.googleapis.com
```